# html highlight entire row

Tags: html, ms-access

I'm sure this is an easy one but I just cant figure it out. I have a MS Access DB where I'm using HTML in DIV tags. However, I'm trying to highlight certain letters and their background for a textbox with a width of 0.2917". I can get it to highlight the text, start a new line, and highlight the next text but I need the background color to go across the full with of the row (or 0.2917"). What would I need to add to the HTML below to get it to do that?

```
<div>
<font color=white style='BACKGROUND-COLOR:#458B00'>V<br></font> 
<font color=black style='BACKGROUND-COLOR:#FFA500'>FMLA<br></font>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you set display:block for each of your font elements, they would be stretched to fit
their first parent with constant width size. since you dont have any elements with constant width, the fonts would stretch to 100% width of the page/window:

please also note that you have to close every style attribute with a semicolon;

```
<div>
<font color=white style='BACKGROUND-COLOR:#458B00; display:block;'>V<br></font> 
<font color=black style='BACKGROUND-COLOR:#FFA500; display:block;'>FMLA<br></font>
</div>
```